# CUDA warp divergence and clock cycles

Tags: cuda

I read that on an SM with 8 SPs, each thread in a warp is mapped to each of the 8 SPs during the execution of one instruction. Hence, a warp is executed in 32/8 = 4 clock cycles.

If so, then suppose I have an if-else statement in the code. Suppose the "then" and "else" branch instructions each take one clock cycle to complete.

How many clock cycles would be needed to complete the if-else statement if divergence occurs? Is it 2, or should it be 2 x 4 = 8? (i.e. in the latter, 2 cycles for each quarter warp)

Appreciate any clarifications!

Answer (score 7):

The granularity is 4 clock cycles - there are 4 instruction phases and each of the 4 phases processes the same instruction for 8 threads (optionally masked if you have conditionals/branching), which is how you get 32 threads executing one instruction every 4 clock cycles. So for a divergent branch as in your example you have a minimum of 4 clocks for one branch and a minimum of 4 clocks for the other branch.